# How to say, "Could you please move over?" (Cantonese and Mandarin)

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

Assume Bob is sitting on the couch.

In Mandarin, how would Alice politely ask Bob to move over and make room for her?

Is this different for Cantonese?

Comment: Usually, people in the subway car say: 能(往那边)窜一下吗？，往那边窜一下呗？. In English, it's like saying *can you scooch down a bit?*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to ask people to move aside to give room

Mandarin:

能請你坐開些嗎? (would you please sit aside a little?)

能請你騰一騰空位嗎? (would you please make some room for me?)

Cantonese:

唔該坐過啲 (please site aside a bit)

唔該坐開小小 (please sit aside a little)

*In Cantonese, to ask people to move aside, we say 唔該借一借, or 唔該借歪, you can use these phrase in your example too*

Answer (score 1):

Mandarin:

> 请你让一让可以吗？

or

> 麻烦你给我腾位置可以吗？

Cantonese:

> 唔该借个位？

The statements are similar.